# How to use webbrowser control to turn the div visibility into visible?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm currently using `System.Windows.Forms` webbrowser control to automate a webpage. Everything works fine to manipulate the `htmlelement` through `webbrowser.document`. However unfortunately i have to click a button which is embedded in a hidden div. so my question is, how should i turn this div 's visibility to visible and click on the button in it?
This is the div which is visible after it has been turned into visible:

```
<div class="box" style="visibility:visible"> 
     <button />
</div>
```

**Ps: the div doesn't have id but only class name (so i think it is dealing with css style)**

Since i'm not able to detect with `webbrowser.document` , how can i retrieve it ? or how can i change the css of class = box using `webbrowser.document`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
yourWebBrowserControl.Document.All["YourButton"].InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: Yep. That's why this guy is over 5,000... :)

Comment: the button is invisible. Unable to detect with the code above. I think one of the alternative is to change this div css in order to show up the div and the button in it... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If I can ask for a bit of clarification: what are you trying to accomplish?

The webbrowser control essentially encapsulates the IE rendering engine and allows you to navigate to a document or URI. When you click this button, are you navigating somewhere? Or is this a form to be submitted?

Comment: when i click this button, it will delete some data record. i have to automate delete the record but however, this button is in the div element which is invisible.

Comment: So is there a request being sent to some web server, or are you handling the event in a local code-behind file?

Comment: i m automating from other website. so the request will be sent to other web server